# Switching between alpha, half-life and span in exponential moving average

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-smoothing

I have been reviewing documentation [here on exponential moving averages.](https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/computation/computation5.html)

I am having a hard time being able to analytically move between the definition of an exponential moving average specified in terms of its alpha decay factor and specifying decay in terms of half-life and span. Is someone able to provide a derivation for the formulas of half-life and span SPECIFICALLY relating to the definition of the exponential moving average provided at the link?

Answer (score 1):

Hi: I've never used center of mass. Here, I'll explain what they mean by span and I'll show what I use for halflife. ( not clear where their formula for halflife is coming from ). Maybe there's another meaning for halflife that I'm not familar with.

1. The span, $ \frac{2}{n+1} $, is the value of $\rho$ that makes the weighted age of the exponentially smoothed estimate equal to the weighted age of the moving average. Using that value results in a smoothed ES series that's very similar to a moving average of width $n$.
2. The model for simple ES is :

$\hat{y}_t = \rho \hat{y}_{t-1} + (1-\rho) x_{t-1}$.

The relation that I use for calculating the value of $\rho$ that results in such a halflife is $\rho^{halflife} = \frac{1}{2}$. They define it similarly, in words, because they say that the halflife is the time it takes for the weight of an observation to become half of what it originally was. But, if you solve my relation for halflife, you get

$\rho = exp\left(\frac{log(\frac{1}{2})}{halflife}\right)$

They have a different expression and I'm not clear on how they obtain it. The expression for $\rho$ that I wrote says, "this is the value of $\rho$ that I need to use when running  ES, in order for the time it takes for the original weight of an observation to become half of what it was originally."

I hope this helps some even though it's not a full answer.